System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer DeserializeAsyncEnumerable works slowly with large json files (10+mb)
I'm using .NET 8, System.Text.Json 8 HttpClient to make request, HttpConnection.ChunkedEncodingReadStream as input stream from the response, and JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable to asynchronously deserialize-enumerate, but unfortunately, it works very slowly for large json objects.
await using var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath);
using var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
using var streamContent = new StreamContent(fileStream);
streamContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
{
    Name = "file",
    FileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath)
};
content.Add(streamContent);

var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "api/v1/streaming")
{
    Content = content
};

var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead,
    cancellationToken);

var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(cancellationToken);
var streamWrapper = new StreamWrapper(responseStream);

var bufferSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
    Converters = {new JsonElementToObjectConverter()},
    DefaultBufferSize = bufferSize
};

await foreach (var batchPart in JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable<BatchPart>(streamWrapper, options,
                   cancellationToken))
{
}

After investigation, I discovered that JsonSerializer is trying to read DefaultBufferSize, but the server/input still does not have enough data to fill it. After this, it tries to deserialize the object, not expecting the buffer to be filled. It works very slowly when taking into account thousands of iterations.
Time            Iteration #N            Buffer to read          Read bytes
12:35:45.145            1               16777216                535
12:35:49.327            2               16777216                4090
12:35:49.33             3               16773126                10671
12:35:49.33             4               16762455                4088
12:35:49.331            5               16758367                10673
...
12:36:04.751            882             24051345                4088
12:36:04.789            883             24047257                10658
12:36:04.827            884             24036599                4088
12:36:04.871            885             24032511                10667
...

In general, it takes ~15 minutes, but the same case only takes ~2 seconds if I am not using chunked-reading.
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead,
    cancellationToken);

The inner implementation explicitly uses fillBuffer: false for deserialization. It looks like the root of problem.
How I can fix performance issue for large json?

Do you have a [mre] to play with? The delay of 4 seconds between first and second iteration looks a bit strange too, maybe something else is in play too.

https://github.com/olehrechukh/SlowJsonDeserialization

I notice, on the server side, your  EnumerateWeatherForecasts(int count) includes a delay between each record: await Task.Delay(10);.  What happens if you remove the delay?

Any chance you could compare the async enumerable deserialization performance of System.Text.Json with the performance of Newtonsoft by testing JsonExtensions.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable<T>() from this answer to Deserializing to AsyncEnumerable using Newtonsoft.Json?

The Microsoft engineer's answer.

@dbc, This delay is used to emulate async work.
If I remove this delay, the method should be converted to sync with IEnumerable. The method will be executed immediately and fill the response buffer.
It is not my case.

@dbc The Netwosoft approach looks much faster compared to System.Text.Json
Thank you. I will investigate this method.

I just built your https://github.com/olehrechukh/SlowJsonDeserialization project, and I can't reproduce your problem.  I am seeing ResponseHeadersRead times that are slightly faster than ResponseContentRead times for larger content.  E.g.: ResponseHeadersRead: 820.6599 ms, ResponseContentRead:  994.8466 ms for 78889364 bytes.  I am running Windows 10, .NET SDK 8.0.203, runtime  8.0.3.

Have you removed Task.Delay(10)?

I followed the instructions in your readme without making any changes.

"It looks very strange. Next benchmark on my local machine with .NET 8.0.203 and Windows 11."
ResponseHeadersRead 26105.1089ms, ResponseContentRead 1973.2426ms, 78889363 bytes
https://i.imgur.com/JL5AjR1.png

Here's a screen shot of my results: https://i.sstatic.net/RcTP2.png.  Maybe you have some local firewall or antivirus running?  Or maybe something about Win11 works differently than Win10?

Was not able to reproduce either (though I've tried on Linux machine). Try updating SDK/runtime to the latest versions. Also try checking out if something like antivirus affects the things.

Hm, very weird case, the bug was detected on production, my teammates also are able to reproduce it.
I'm using ,NET SDK 8.0.203
